# How can I change the Button without the code opening a new window with the changed button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Im trying to make a simple shop which changes the background of the main window. But when you click the buy button (buyblue) it should change the text on the button to gekauft(sold in german). But because of the button beeing in another definition i acessed it with return and when i now click the button it opens a new window with the changed button. Is there a way to fix it that only the button on the already open window changes and no new window opens?

Its written in python 3 and with the tkinter module.

```
click = 10
bluecost = 10
def openshop():
    global root2
    root2 = Tk()
    root2.title("SIMPLE CLICKER SHOP")
    root2.geometry("700x400")
    root2.resizable(height = False, width = False)
    root2.configure(bg = "white")


    buttonblue = Button(root2, text = "3000 Clicks", bg = "maroon1", command = buyblue)
    buttonblue.place(x = 120, y = 120)
    return buttonblue

def buyblue():
    global click
    global bluecost
    buttonblue=openshop()

    if click >= int(bluecost):
            click -= int(bluecost)
            global root
            global label
            global click1
            root["bg"]="blue"
            click1["bg"]="blue"
            label["bg"]="blue"
            buttonblue["bg"]="green"
            buttonblue["text"] = "Gekauft"
            bluecost = 0
```

Is there another way to pass a variable which is used in a defintion to another defintion?

Comment: You're already using global in a lot of places. Why don't you use global for buttonblue? That being said, I don't think it's a good design.

Comment: I cant use global for button blue because its defined in a defintion. Edit: Im pretty new to python and coding so this might be just a lack of knowledge.

Comment: You don't want another window to be created? Your code gives error that `click` is not defined

Comment: this isnt the whole code i defined this things at the beginning.

Comment: Another question: Why do you have two roots (root and root2)? The fact that you're doing root2 = Tk() in your openshop function looks suspicious. I'm guessing that you're calling Tk() twice in your code somewhere.

Comment: Its the shop window which pops up.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the tkinter window in the function `openshop`. It means that whenever you run the function `openshop`, another window will be created. You have to modify your function from:

```
...
def openshop():
    global root2
    root2 = Tk()  #< creates the window
    ...
```

to:

```
...
global root2
root2 = Tk() #< creates the window
def openshop():
    ...
```

This will reconfigure the root each time the `openshop` is run again but will not create another window.

Comment: But then it opens a unconfigured window and when openshop is triggered it opens nothing

Comment: @SwenSunyaro Yeah. When the openshop is triggered, it gets configured. Though your question doesn't explain much about what you want to happen.

Comment: If you want the window to open once when the openshop is triggered, then there is also a solution.

Comment: I want the button to change its text after the background got purchased and i mad a defintion in which this gets defined but instead of only changing the text it opens a new window with the new button with the new text on it and leaves the original shop window unchanged.

Comment: @SwenSunyaro Please provide the whole code separately. This will help understand what to do.